# ObjectInputStream stops loop

Tags: java, udp, serializable, objectinputstream

So I'm creating a server and client program,

**Server Class:**

```
 package Networking;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server {

    private static ArrayList<Socket> sockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();
    private static ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream>os = new ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream>();
    private static ArrayList<ObjectInputStream> is = new ArrayList<ObjectInputStream>();

    private static ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(7321);
        System.out.println("Server Started");

        int fps = 60;
        double timePerTick = 1000000000 / fps;
        double delta = 0.0D;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timer = 0L;
        int ticks = 0;
        while (true) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
            timer += now - lastTime;
            lastTime = now;
            if (delta >= 1.0D) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                if(socket != null){
                    sockets.add(socket);
                    os.add(new ObjectOutputStream(sockets.get(sockets.size()-1).getOutputStream()));
                    is.add(new ObjectInputStream(sockets.get(sockets.size()-1).getInputStream()));
                    players.add((Player)is.get(sockets.size()-1).readObject());


                }
                ticks++;
                delta -= 1.0D;
            }
            for(int i = 0 ;i < sockets.size();i++){
                os.get(i).writeObject(players);
                os.get(i).flush();
            }
            if (timer >= 1000000000L) {
                ticks = 0;
                timer = 0L;
            }
            for(int i =0; i < sockets.size();i++){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client Class**

```
package Networking;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.sun.prism.paint.Stop;

import Dynamics.Display;

public class Client implements Runnable {
    private final String serverAddress = "localhost";
    private static int PORT = 7321;
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private boolean connected = false;
    private static Player player = null;
    private boolean isrunning = false;

    private ArrayList<Player> enemy;

    private Thread thread;
    private Display display;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        Client c = new Client();
        c.connect();
        c.start();
    }
    public Client(){
        player = new Player();
        display = new Display("Game: " + player.getName());
    }

    public void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException{
        try{
            socket = new Socket(serverAddress, PORT);
            connected = true;
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out.writeObject(player);


        }catch(UnknownHostException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }


    private synchronized void start(){
        if(isrunning)
            return;
        isrunning = true;
        this.thread = new Thread(this);
        this.thread.start();
        this.display.getFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
    public void run() {
        int fps = 60;
        double timePerTick = 1000000000 / fps;
        double delta = 0.0D;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timer = 0L;
        int ticks = 0;
        while (isrunning) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
            timer += now - lastTime;
            lastTime = now;
            if (delta >= 1.0D) {
                tick();
                render();
                ticks++;
                delta -= 1.0D;
            }
            if (timer >= 1000000000L) {
                ticks = 0;
                timer = 0L;
            }
        }

    }

    public void tick(){}
    public void render(){

        CheckEnemys();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void CheckEnemys() {
        try {
            enemy = (ArrayList<Player>)in.readObject();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(enemy.size());
    }
}
```

My problem comes when I run the loop to constantly check for new players and the loop just stops after one iteration . The player class is serializable with default constructor and name. Idk y the loop stops though

Answer (score 0):

When you open an `ObjectInputStream` it will block until the other side flushes its `ObjectOutputStream` and writes the header. Make sure that you open the output stream first and flush it immediately.

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.flush();
in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Your `CheckEnemys` method will also block until it receives an object from the server, which only happens when a client joins. You should run the method in a separate thread and feed events from it to your main thread through a synchronized queue.

As an aside, you should `Thread.sleep()` between ticks, not loop constantly checking the clock.

You should also `reset()` your `ObjectOutputStream` after you write messages or it will hold references to everything that's been written, preventing garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do any I/O whatsoever in the accept loop, and that include creating `ObjectinputStreams` or `ObjectOutputStreams`. All that should be in a separate thread's `run()` method.